# Showing that numbers of the form 10101010...1 are composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, geometric-progressions

I want to prove that all numbers of the form 1010101010...1 are composite except for 101.

I'm able to prove it for all numbers with an even number of ones, but I can't figure out any ideas for the remaining numbers.

Comment: Putnam, 1989-A1. See, for example, http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~dale/putnam/1989.pdf

Comment: This is a geometric progression $1+r+\cdots + r^n$ for $r=10^2$. Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series. The numerator and denominator both factor in a natural way. Look closely at each part in the case of an odd number of 1's (meaning $n$ is *even*).

Comment: I did, I'm talking about the case where the exponent is odd

Comment: *This* was a Putnam problem?! The standards have surely increased over the years.

Comment: Preparing for the exam? :p

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 You should check out [1988 - A1](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol881.html)

Comment: @gowrath Nah just for fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have numbers of the form $\dfrac{100^n-1}{99}=\dfrac{(10^{n}-1)(10^{n}+1)}{9\times 11}$:

- If $n$ is odd you have $\dfrac{100^{2k-1}-1}{99}=\dfrac{10^{2k-1}-1}{9} \times \dfrac{10^{2k-1}+1}{11}$
- If $n$ is even you have $\dfrac{100^{2k}-1}{99}=\dfrac{10^{2k}-1}{99} \times \dfrac{10^{2k}+1}{1}$

and these factors are all integers, though some may be equal to $1$ when $k=1$

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't see 100=10^2

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  view the number as a geometric series.  The first term is $1$ and the ratio is $100$.  Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series, then see the numerator as a difference of two squares.